# How to compute the riemannian curvature of a compact riemannian manifold?

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

Let $M$ be a compact Riemannian manifold. How would I compute the Riemannian curvature of $M$ using Gaussian curvature (or otherwise using the exponential map and Jacobi fields)?

Comment: It sounds as if you have a particular situation in mind. To avoid the [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), could you please try to explain in more detail what information you have and what insight you hope to find?

Comment: Perhaps Achinta does want an answer to the attempted solution (as I often do), thus avoiding the XY problem altogether

Answer (score 2):

If you have the exponential map at $p\in M$, this is easy.  Just exponentiate the 2-dimensional direction you want to compute the sectional curvature of.  This gives you a surface in $M$ passing through $p$.  Its Gaussian curvature at $p$ is precisely the sectional curvature of $M$ in this 2-dimensional direction.